# How to install UTF8 locale on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, encoding

I have a PostgreSQL 8.4 on Windows 7 machine, and my issue is that I have only the `win1251` locale.

So when I create a database, I choose the UTF8 encoding and can select only `lc_collate  = Russian_Russia.Win1251`. And when I get any errors when I use JDBC I get unreadable logs.

How can I set a locale like `en_US.UTF8` or `ru_RU.UTF8`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL 8.4 supports only one locales that is selected in installation time. You need to rerun initdb statement with different locales (but only one can be used) or you can migrate to 9.x version, that supports more locales.

Comment: I tried reinstall PostgreSQL 8.4 but not see any locale selection in instalation. For select locale i can not use one click installer?

Comment: Long time I didn't use a 8.4, but I remember, so there was a some possibilities - maybe your system missing some locales (postgres depends on system resources), maybe you use a some different installator. You can use a initdb command manually without reinstallation, but it needs some deeper knowledge  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881845/how-to-manually-configure-and-start-postgresql-on-windows